# Data Loading and Update

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am new to Zeppelin and I'm researching some stuff, so I have two specific questions:

1. What sources can be used to load data from? Is is possible Excel Files, Oracle or mysql database?
2. How the data is updated, for example if I get the information from a CSV file and there is new every day how can it be updated?

Thanks in advance for your help.